# Can't convert epoch to readable format in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Trying to convert epoch time in ansible but the task fails because i am trying to loop over json output.

What i am trying to do is:

1. register the output from win_find module
2. filtering only the creationtime value from this register (eposh value)
3. using strftime filter to convert epoch value to readable value

   ```
   - win_find:
       path: <path>
     register: register_path

    - set_fact:
        epoch_format: "{{ register_path | json_query('files[*].creationtime')}}"
   ```

And this is the creationtime filter output

```
    "ansible_facts": {
    "epoch_format": [
        1564668211.4169703,
        1564668218.4144595,
        1564668227.1259055,
        1564668236.2201614,
        1564668243.202953,
        1564668251.3371267,
        1564668259.5494978,
        1564668268.9736576
```

Now i try to convert

```
- set_fact:
    readable_format: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime({{ item }}) }}"
  loop: '{{ epoch_format}}'
```

this is what i get back

```
     "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', 
       got '}'. String: {{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime({{ item }}) }}",
```

if i try to quote {{ item }} >> '{{ item }}' i get this back:

```
     "msg": "Invalid value for epoch value ({{ item }})",
```

Is there anyway to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should remove the curly braces from `item`:

```
- set_fact:
    readable_format: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(item) }}"
  loop: '{{ epoch_format}}'
```

hope it helps

Comment: This is right, but it will continuously overwrite `readable_format`. Need to first declare `readable_format: []` and then do something like `readable_format: "{{ readable_format + ['%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(item) ]}}"`

Comment: you are right, i bypassed this programming logic error. i was just focusing in the question itself about converting the epoch value